# How to create a directory inside the C:\ProgramData in Python?

Tags: python, directory, path, mkdir, pathlib

How to create a directory inside the C:\ProgramData in Python?

I want to create Foo directory inside C:\ProgramData in Python

```
import os
from pathlib import Path, PurePath, PosixPath,PurePosixPath,PureWindowsPath,WindowsPath

path = WindowsPath("C:/PrgramData/Foo")

path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: It looks like you might be attempting to create the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with the makedirs() function from the os module as follows:

```
import os

os.makedirs(r'C:\ProgramData\Foo', exist_ok=True)
```